# R data.table optimising. Overdraft financial data

Tags: r, performance, data.table, financial

Given the following data.table with financial data (35 million rows):

DT:

```
userId  Date         balance  overdraft (boolean)
600     2014-11-01   -100     1
600     2014-11-02   1000     0
600     2014-11-03   -100     1
600     2014-11-04   -100     1
600     2014-11-05   100      0
600     2014-11-06   100      0
700     2014-11-01   -100     1
700     2014-11-02   1000     0
700     2014-11-03   -100     1
700     2014-11-04   -100     1
700     2014-11-05   -100     1
700     2014-11-06   100      0
```

The case:

a.- Total number of max. consecutive overdraft days by userId.

```
userId  maxConsecutiveOverdraftDays   
600     2
700     3
800     0
900     1
1000    5
```

In this case I done the following:

```
acum = FALSE

for (i in 1:nrow(DT)) {

    if (DT[i]$overdraft == 1 ) {
      if (acum == TRUE) 
  {

        DT[i]$acumBalance <- DT[i]$balance + DT[i-1]$balance 
        DT[i]$totalConsecutiveOverdraftDays   <- DT[i]$overdraft + DT[i-1]$overdraft
  }

      if (DT[i]$userId == DT[i+1]$userId 
      && DT[i+1]$overdraft == 1 ) 
  {

        acum = TRUE
  }  
    else { acum = FALSE }
}
}

DT[,maxConsecutiveOverdraftDays:=max(totalConsecutiveOverdraftDays),by=userId]
```

It takes more than 12 hours to finish.

How can I improve the code and reduce the computation time?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't say if this will help your performance problem, but `rle` is helpful here for nice short code. Since the value of overdraft is always zero or one, we can take the max of a product of length and value:

```
> aggregate(overdraft~userId, df, FUN=function(x) {
+   r <- rle(x)
+   max(r$lengths * r$values)
+ })
  userId overdraft
1    600         2
2    700         3
```

Comment: `data.table` adaptation: `DT[, rle(overdraft), by=userId][, max(lengths * values), by=userId]`

Comment: proc.time() - timer
    user  system elapsed 
    6.90    0.28    7.18

Comment: 12 hours to 7 seconds? Whoa.

Answer (score 2):

#### Update: [#686](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/686) is now implemented in [1.9.5](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/commit/b8c1b01ac9453750d0e99a388522877eec38f06b). From [NEWS](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/README.md):

> 7) `rleid()`, a convenience function for generating a run-length type id column to be used in grouping operations is now implemented. Closes [#686](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/686). Check `?rleid` examples section for usage scenarios.

With this function, we can do:

```
require(data.table) ## 1.9.5+
dt[, .(overdraft = overdraft[1L], .N), by=.(userId, 
      rleid(overdraft))][overdraft == 1L, max(N), by=userId]
```

---

There's a [FR #686](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/686) open to implement such a function. But this'll have to be implemented along with fast rank function. We have not gotten to it yet.

Until then, you can do it this way:

```
dt[, .(overdraft = overdraft[1L], .N), by=.(userId, 
    cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(overdraft) != 0L)))][overdraft == 1L, max(N), by=userId]
#    userId V1
# 1:    600  2
# 2:    700  3
```

Edit: Corrected logic as pointed out by @Dirk. Thanks!

Comment: proc.time() - timer
    user  system elapsed 
    6.90    0.28    7.18

Answer (score 1):

This one-liner should do the trick:

```
overdraft[, daysoverdraft:=seq(.N)-1, by=cumsum(overdraft == 0)]
```

Let's test with a simple set of data:

```
overdraft = data.table(userId=rep(1:10^3, each=350),
                       date=rep(1:350, 10^3),
                       balance=round(rnorm(35*10^3)*100),
                       overdraft=0)
overdraft[balance < 0, overdraft:=1]
```

With 350k rows it runs acceptable fast (~1.2 seconds on my laptop), however, not even close to the speed of Arun's answer, which is at least 20x faster.